# Reading file in free format input in ada

Tags: file-io, ada

I need to take input from a file like this:

Let's say file name is test.dat and its like this:

```
keyword1 123456a
keyword2 small hard sour
keyword2 midsize firm bland
keyword2 large hard sour
    keyword1 

         2234567
keyword1 3234567
keyword1 4234567
    keyword2 
        small 
        soft 
        sour
keyword1 123456a
    keyword2 midsize hard bland
keyword1 123456A
    keyword2 large firm sweet
keyword1 AAAAAAA
    keyword2 midsize hard bland
keyword1 BBBBBBA
    keyword2 large firm sweet
```

I need to detect keyword1 and read the next seven characters string and then I need to detect keywords2 and read next three strings and so on. As you can see there can be any amount of white space before and after any string in the file.

I am new to ada. Please help.

Comment: What sort of help do you want? What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I thought of reading line by line and then tokenizing the string with space delimiter but there can be any amount of spaces between two strings.

Comment: A reasonable start. There are functions in `Ada.Strings`, like `Index` you can use to find the index of a pattern (or a non-space character) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at GNAT.AWK. It likely is one of the simplest way to do this parsing automatically. Something like:

```
procedure On_Keyword1 is
begin
   Put_Line ("Field1 = " & GNAT.AWK.Field (2));
end On_Keyword1;

procedure On_Keyword2 is
begin
   Put_Line ("Word1=" & GNAT.AWK.Field (2)
             & " Word2=" & GNAT.AWK.Field (3)
             & " Word3=" & GNAT.AWK.Field (4));
end On_Keyword2;

GNAT.AWK.Register (1, "Keyword1", On_Keyword1'Access);
GNAT.AWK.Register (1, "Keyword2", On_Keyword2'Access);
```